# Netty SctpMultiChannel

Tags: netty, sctp

Is there support for SCTP multichannel in Netty library?
I have checked the source code and it depends on the SctpChannel class and there is no use to the com.sun.nio.sctp.SctpMultiChannel.

And if the answer is 'No', then is there any plan to support this?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are is not support and we also do not plan on it atm. That said if you feel like you need it I would be more then happy to review a PR in netty for it.